# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know what's going on here? I don't get why getElementByTagName should be a function in the first place, it's already inside a function and it's called by a submit button.

```
    <body>        
    <form novalidate>
      First Name:<input id="fname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\W]" type="text" name="First Name">
      Last Name:<input id="lname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\W]" type="text" name="Last Name">
      Number:<input id="num" pattern="[0-9\D]"  type="text" name="Number">
      Email:<input id="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\D\W._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/" type="text" name="Email">
      <button type="button" id="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>


<script>
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function() {
var inputFields = document.getElementByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
  var theInput = inputFields[i].value;
  var thePattern = new RegExp(inputFields[i].pattern);
  var theTest = thePattern.test(theInput);
  console.log(theTest);

  if (theTest === false) {
    console.log(inputFields[i].name + " is incorrect");
  }

}
} )

 </script>
```